# Logging Application Block 6.0 text formatter template tokens

Tags: c#, logging, token, formatter

I need the list of the text formatter template tokens that can be used in Enterprise Library Loggin Application Block text formatter configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the list of the tokens that can be used to format log entries, here it is:

```
{message}
{category}
{priority}
{eventid}
{severity}
{title}
{timestamp}
{timestamp()}
{timestamp(local)}
{timestamp(FixedFormatUSDate)}
{timestamp(FixedFormatISOInternationalDate)}
{timestamp(FixedFormatTime)}
{machine}
{localMachine}
{appDomain}
{localAppDomain}
{processId}
{localProcessId}
{processName}
{localProcessName}
{threadName}
{win32ThreadId}
{dictionary()}
{keyvalue()}
{newline}
{tab}
{property()}
```

Dictionary example: {dictionary({key} - {value}{newline})}

List is extracted from the Logging Application Block source code, which can be downloaded from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169621.aspx)

Comment: Apply to ***Ent.Lib 5.0***? How can I add my customs values like _HttpCurrent.User.Identity.Name_ ?